# My sitemap is valid but I still get erros

Tags: sitemap.xml

all I'm trying to upload my sitemap to Google search console and according to sitemap validators everything is valid but I'm still getting error

Sitemap can be read but contains errors

Invalid UTF-8 encoding

3

Sitemap contains "C0" or "C1" control codes (other than "CR", "LF", "HT" and "FF") or non-character codes.

Examples

Row 1

Row 2

Row 3

Here's my sitemap:

```
  <loc>https://d38cubqnlqem3h.cloudfront.net/</loc>

  <lastmod>2023-04-30</lastmod>

  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

  <priority>1.0</priority>
```

```
  <loc>https://d38cubqnlqem3h.cloudfront.net/index.html</loc>

  <lastmod>2023-04-30</lastmod>

  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

  <priority>0.8</priority>
```

```
  <loc>https://d38cubqnlqem3h.cloudfront.net/index2.html</loc>

  <lastmod>2023-04-30</lastmod>

  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

  <priority>0.8</priority>
```

```
  <loc>https://d38cubqnlqem3h.cloudfront.net/ocuprime.html</loc>

  <lastmod>2023-04-30</lastmod>

  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

  <priority>0.7</priority>
```

```
  <loc>https://d38cubqnlqem3h.cloudfront.net/neurotonix.html</loc>

  <lastmod>2023-04-30</lastmod>

  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

  <priority>0.7</priority>
```